# Android: Navigation/hamburger menu won't open after adding RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, appbar

My end goal is to create a simple material designed todo list. I'm only in the early stages, but I've hit an issue I can't seem to get through. When I add the recycler view to the main activity, the navigation menu won't show when I swipe from the left, or when I hit the hamburger menu. When I comment it out, it works fine. Does anyone know what the issue could be? I'm pretty sure it's something simple, but I've researched online and here on StackOverflow, and can't seem to come up with an answer. You all have been so helpful in the past, I'm hoping some magic can happen again!

I'm following the tutorial series here with a minor adjustment starting in video #6, where I want the recycler view in the main activity, instead of the navigation drawer:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD

Thanks!

Here is the layout in question:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_overall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Include app_bar so the bar shows after drawer is opened -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                android:name="cca.habitrpgnativeclient.com.NavigationDrawerFragment"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Tasks -->
    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/tasks_layout"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"-->
        <!--android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tasks_left_padding" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, here is the method in question:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setup toolbar
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Setup navigation menu
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)), toolbar);

    // Setup tasks
//        recyclerView  = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_layout);
//        taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(this, getTasks());
//        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
```

(Thanks for the edit, I added the other method as well)

Comment: In the future, paste code into the question. If you want to post links, you can do that too. But the question should stand alone, as your code is presumably going to change over time. These questions and answers need to be usable despite those changes.

Comment: Good point, I'll keep that in mind for the future. I didn't know how the formatting would work when posting in the question, so I figured I'd just post the link since it was there. Turns out the code was super easily formatted though! Good to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your `RecyclerView` is overlaying the `LinearLayout` (containing your `DrawerLayout`) on the Z axis. Hence, your `DrawerLayout` is not going to receive any touch events, which is why your bezel swipe does not work. Apparently the `app_bar` `<include>` is a `Toolbar`, where I presume your hamburger is, and that too is being overlaid by the `RecyclerView`, which is why that does not work.

The main UI of your activity goes where you have the `FrameLayout`. So, either replace the `FrameLayout` with the `RecyclerView`, or put the `RecyclerView` in the `FrameLayout`, or put the `RecyclerView` in a fragment that you load into that `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I replaced the FrameLayout with the RecyclerView and it works perfect. Thanks!